# Does less use of variables in Java class help better performance?

Tags: java, android, performance, variables

I am developing an android application and I need to improve its performance. If I use less variables in each class, would that help me to achieve better performance?

Comment: Define "less" and "more" variables. Are we talking about 100 vs 1000000000000?

Comment: It depends on what you do with those variables. Introducing variables can actually improve performance (for example, if you use them to store the result of a method call instead of calling that method multiple times).

Comment: if am trying to get date, then i use Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance(); then i get day,year month from that variable, i am wasting memory by declaring a variable called c. am i right??

Comment: Try and find out as to which function call in particular is slowing your application rather than lowering the variables. I don't think lowering the number of variables would have any impact on performance

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a ridiculous amount of variables, you won't notice any difference (and chances are the compiler will optimize redundant local variables away anyway). If you want to improve your application's performance you'd be better served in concentrating on improving your algorithms and reducing the amount of accesses to external resources.

Comment: thank you friend. Let me by your suggetion

Answer (score 0):

***Maybe*** help performance, but it's better to see this helpful online book about [Java Enterprise Performance](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/javabook.html) about java Performance. Memory isn't the only thing play role in performance.